# Excel SQL - question mark

Tags: sql, excel

I use sometimes questionmark in Excel-SQL

```
select accountnum,name from Customer where accountnum = ?
```

this works fine. If I add another select statement it fail -

```
select accountnum,name,(select salary from --------- )
from Customer where accountnum = ?
```

Is this not possible ?  I use question mark so users can insert values.

Comment: that doesn't look like a valid sql statement.  I'm guessing you want a JOIN so that you can pull the salary from one table and accountnum and name from the Customer table.  Perhaps something like this? `SELECT Customer.accountnum,Customer.name,table2.salary FROM Customer INNER JOIN table2 ON Customer.ID = table2.ID WHERE Customer.accountnum = ?`

Comment: In order to do what you are attempting, you will need to make sure that the select in your select only returns one record